# Unable to run `bundle install` and restore my gemlock file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I deleted my gemlock file, then I ran bundle install but got these errors

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties"

gem list in Gemfile:

```
coffee-rails (~> 4.2) was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on railties (>= 4.0.0)
jquery-rails (>= 4.3.1, ~> 4.3) was resolved to 4.3.1, which depends on railties (>= 4.2.0)
material-ui (~> 0.7.3.2) was resolved to 0.7.3.2, which depends on railties (~> 4.0)
rails (~> 5.1.2) was resolved to 5.1.2, which depends on railties (= 5.1.2)
sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)
web-console (>= 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on railties (>= 5.0)
```

I could get ruby version through `ruby -v` but couldn't even get my rails version through `rails -v`. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `Gemfile`’s rails entry:

```
- gem 'rails'
+ gem 'rails', '< 5.0'
```

Your `Gemfile.lock` was created before `Rails5` era and hence open-ended dependency was fine. Now it’s resolved to `Rails5`, enforcing `railties = 5.1.2`, which all your other gems are not ready for.